# 100% stacked area plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-area-chart

I want to create a 100% stacked area plot in R Studio. For my other graphs, I am using ggplot2. I know this is an easy question and there are resources online, but I just cant do it.

time is supposed to be on the x-axis. And the data is in the column 'example_col'. As you see, these values are seperated by comma and each row has a sum of 1.

```
time       example_col
00:00:00   0.018,0.600,0.263,0.119,0.000
00:05:00   0.007,0.621,0.207,0.120,0.045
00:10:00   0.000,0.665,0.265,0.069,0.000
00:15:00   0.008,0.640,0.242,0.109,0.000
00:20:00   0.021,0.529,0.287,0.114,0.049
00:25:00   0.000,0.579,0.262,0.159,0.000
00:30:00   0.021,0.714,0.265,0.000,0.000
...        ...
```

I can separate the data into seperate columns using substr(). I have found these solutions, but I cant make it work:

[ggplot2 plotting a 100% stacked area chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50608379/ggplot2-plotting-a-100-stacked-area-chart)

[Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format)

How do I do it?

Thanks so much!

Comment: do you mean, they sum to 100 for each "row" that you have?

Comment: yes exactly :) I added it to the question

Answer (score 2):

I think this is mainly a reading data and class conversion problem.

Here one way (comments in the code)

```
library(tidyverse)

df<-read.table(text = "
0.018,0.600,0.263,0.119,0.000
0.007,0.621,0.207,0.120,0.045
0.000,0.665,0.265,0.069,0.000
0.008,0.640,0.242,0.109,0.000
0.021,0.529,0.287,0.114,0.049
0.000,0.579,0.262,0.159,0.000
0.021,0.714,0.265,0.000,0.000")

df %>%
## split the data
separate(V1, into = paste0("V", 1:5), sep = ",") %>%
## convert the values to numeric
## add an identifier column for the rows, this will be used for your x position
mutate(across(everything(), as.numeric),     
       group = seq_along(V1)) %>%
## make long
pivot_longer(starts_with("V")) %>%

## now plot
ggplot() +
geom_col(aes(as.character(group), value, fill = name))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It took me a while, but it now works like a charm :)